# MySQL Relational Database Design for Transactions/Fees

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm curious on the best design pattern for my application. I have clients who I process transactions for. I then charge them a fee. I then transfer the fee to me, and the remaining balance to them. Currently I have a transaction table to support all of this, and I feel it's ugly.

Transaction table has

```
ID | trans_id | amount | type | status | client_id | transfer_id | created | modified
```

With this model, I assume I can store various types of transactions. I could store a `charge` in the amount of $100.00 for client 1 and also store a `fee` for it in the amount of $2.00. When I transfer the funds, I could add a row of the `transfer` type, and then update the previous rows with the ID of this transfer. But I feel that this will make the queries very complex.

Should I instead have a separate table for `charge`, `fee` and `transfer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a relational database with different tables would be highly beneficial and more efficient. A relation design structure would reduce redundancies with the use of primary and foreign keys and will prevent duplicates. So go with a relational database with the separate tables.